# attempt to call a string value

Tags: string, lua

Just trying to generate a series (loop of 10) random hexadecimal strings..  Here's my code

```
math.randomseed(os.time())

function genRanHex(length)
    genRanHex = ""
    for count = 1, length, 1 do
        num = math.random(0,15)
        genRanHex = genRanHex..string.upper(string.format("%x", num))
    end
    return genRanHex
end

for c = 1, 10, 1 do
    print(genRanHex(8))
end
```

getting the following error:

lua: main.lua:13: attempt to call a string value (global 'genRanHex')
stack traceback:
main.lua:13: in main chunk
[C]: in ?

Thank you for any assistance

Comment: Your function and the variable you use inside that function use the same name.

Answer (score 3):

You're overwriting the global variable `genRanHex` that holds the function with the string `genRanHex` you're building in the function. The solution is to (1) localize everything *and* (2) use different names or (3) get rid of the inefficient string concatenation entirely. Here's how I would rewrite it, leveraging `string.char` to implicitly do the concat:

```lua
math.randomseed(os.time())

local function randomHexBytes(n)
    if n == 0 then return end
    return ("%X"):format(math.random(0, 0xF)):byte(), randomHexBytes(n-1)
end

local function genRanHex(n)
    return string.char(randomHexBytes(n))
end

for _ = 1, 10 do
    print(genRanHex(8))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a different name for the function and local variable.

Better yet, add the `local` keyword to the variable declaration so that it's a local instead of a global.

Comment: `num` should also get a `local`.